# Клавиши на клавиатуре ноутбука

Tags: клавиатура, ноутбук

Недавно стали не работать клавиши 6,8,9 и 1 на нум паде. При это все прочищено, и если попытаться протыкать одну из клавиш , то остальные начинают работать хотя их даже не трогали, в чем причина ? Какая поломка и что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Клавиатура это сетка x на y. На пересечении линий стоят кнопки. Похоже одна из X линий оборвалась или образовалась микротрещина. Отвалилась скорее не в разъеме - там отваливаются группы по 8 . где-то рядом с названными клавишами.

[image: клава]

В детстве я чинил клавиатуру припаивая проволочку на место трещины. Сейчас её можно заделать лаком для восстановления обогревательных элементов авто. Но это в случае если доберетесь до пленки. В ноутбучных обычно эта часть не разборная.

Comment: Магическим образом сегодня клавиши работают без перебоев, вчера я ими не пользовался вообще в итоге. А сегодня вон, работают как будто не ломались. Теперь еще интереснее что с этим делать. Да эта часть не разбирается, тут сразу плата идет и металлическая пластина какая то

Comment: Под металлической пластиной пленка с контактами. Закажи новую клавиатуру когда ещё что-нибудь отвалится) трещина пока не большая будет проявляться только при нагреве. Потом расползется. Может через месяц, может через 5лет